# How to make a pulse animation on a svg path?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm able to make the pulse animation on the heart but on the second icon it's sliding, I don't understand why.

```html
<svg>
    <g transform="translate(50, 50)">
        <path transform="translate(-50, -50)" d="M82.6,50L82.6,50c-0.2-8.1-6.9-15.2-15.1-15.2c-4.8,0-9,2.4-11.8,6c-2.8-3.6-7-6-11.8-6c-8.3,0-15,7.2-15.1,15.2h0c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0.7,20.5,26.6,29,26.6,29s26.3-8.4,27.1-28.9c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1C82.6,50.1,82.6,50.1,82.6,50z"/>
 <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" type="scale"       values="1;1.5;1" additive="sum" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1042.816 1297.406">
    <g transform="translate(50, 50)">
        <path transform="translate(-50, -50)" d="M698.467,114.89a10.209,10.209,0,0,1-3.787-.817c-13.05-5.219-51.65-19.04-65.74-21.65s-23.48-4.96-19.83-14.09,7.57-24.78,7.57-24.78,5.57-30.79,7.61-34.44c1.618-2.894,3.594-3.82,7.465-3.82,1.01,0,2.149.062,3.445.17,6.26.52,26.61,3.65,25.3,8.87s-2.6,7.92,8.87,10.09,49.374,13.388,51.457,18.084c2.47,5.567-3.977,24.786-8.147,35.217-3.732,9.321-4.754,27.166-14.213,27.166M628.979,10.6c-6.16,0-8.353,2.8-10.209,12.954-2.76,15.01-13.91,53.56-14.82,56.671a3.161,3.161,0,0,1-.14.4c-4.27,10.521,1.78,12.86,22,16.231,20.35,3.389,57.3,17,63.09,18.889,3.735,1.222,8.923,4.074,13.182,4.074,2.924,0,5.41-1.343,6.688-5.484,3.13-10.17,12.78-39.649,16.95-52.17s-4.95-18.79-17.74-21.92c-11.46-2.8-29.64-7.5-39.67-11.45a4.522,4.522,0,0,1-2.87-4.26c.14-8.97-6.28-9.83-22.41-12.2-6.227-.916-10.719-1.734-14.051-1.734" fill="#4cb5e3"/>
        <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="1;1.5;1" additive="sum" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a different transform like so:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1042.816 1297.406">
  <g transform="translate(664.6295, 65.2095)">
    <path  transform="translate(-664.6295, -65.2095)" d="M698.467,114.89a10.209,10.209,0,0,1-3.787-.817c-13.05-5.219-51.65-19.04-65.74-21.65s-23.48-4.96-19.83-14.09,7.57-24.78,7.57-24.78,5.57-30.79,7.61-34.44c1.618-2.894,3.594-3.82,7.465-3.82,1.01,0,2.149.062,3.445.17,6.26.52,26.61,3.65,25.3,8.87s-2.6,7.92,8.87,10.09,49.374,13.388,51.457,18.084c2.47,5.567-3.977,24.786-8.147,35.217-3.732,9.321-4.754,27.166-14.213,27.166M628.979,10.6c-6.16,0-8.353,2.8-10.209,12.954-2.76,15.01-13.91,53.56-14.82,56.671a3.161,3.161,0,0,1-.14.4c-4.27,10.521,1.78,12.86,22,16.231,20.35,3.389,57.3,17,63.09,18.889,3.735,1.222,8.923,4.074,13.182,4.074,2.924,0,5.41-1.343,6.688-5.484,3.13-10.17,12.78-39.649,16.95-52.17s-4.95-18.79-17.74-21.92c-11.46-2.8-29.64-7.5-39.67-11.45a4.522,4.522,0,0,1-2.87-4.26c.14-8.97-6.28-9.83-22.41-12.2-6.227-.916-10.719-1.734-14.051-1.734" fill="#4cb5e3"/>
    <animateTransform attributeType="XML" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="1;1.5;1" additive="sum" begin="0s" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In order to get the new transformation I'm using `getBBox()` for the path. This is returning in this case `SVGRect {x: 602.5171508789062, y: 10.600000381469727, width: 124.22491455078125, height: 109.21900939941406}`

In order to get the transformation for the path:

```
x = 602.5171508789062 + 124.22491455078125/2
y = 10.600000381469727 + 109.21900939941406/2
```

Comment: What is `getBBox()` ?

Comment: [getBBox() allows us to determine the coordinates of the smallest rectangle in which the object fits.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)

Answer (score 0):

possibly helpful when using [the above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60184868/17681683): when you call the `getBBox()` and get the json in the console, you can use the following python3 script to get the proper `transform-origin` values:

```
import json
import re

json_string = "{x: 290.36505126953125, y: 58.97667694091797, width: 26.782958984375, height: 24.51531982421875}"

json_string = re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'"\1":', json_string)

loaded = json.loads(json_string)

print(f'{loaded["x"] + loaded["width"]/2}px {loaded["y"] + loaded["height"]/2}px')
```

so then you can slap the following on the element you want to animate:

```
transform-origin: 303.75653076171875px 71.23433685302734px;
```